# Where to create custom extensions for Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions

Some articles encourage to create custom extensions in `app/code` and some other encourage to create them under `vendor`. Are both these two methods fine?

What if I want to override a module in `vendor`? Do I need to write my custom module also inside `vendor` folder or `app/code`?

Do they act as codepools as in Magento 1.x?

Please anyone clarify the purpose of each directories.

Comment: According to me we need to make it in app/code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at the folders `app/code` and `vendor` as the codepools in M1, but they are not really codepools.
There is no "codepool" concept in M1.

- `vendor` folder is for modules you download via composer. You should not write code in that folder.
- `app/code` is your playground. Add your own extensions here.

If you need to rewrite/extend something in the `vendor` folder you can do it in the `app/code` folder. Just make sure you specify the soft dependency in the `module.xml` of your module, in the same way you did it in M1 in `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml` file.
The only difference is that in m2 they are not actually dependencies. They are sequences.
This way your module will be loaded after the one from the `vendor` folder

Comment: Not entirely true. If you install M2 via github `app/code` is not a playground ;)

Comment: @Marius : Thanks a lot. It cleared the doubt I had. If you want to override `XM`L file in a vendor module, do we still have to mention the dependencies in `module.xml `?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. Yes and no. You get the core modules in `app/code` in that case, but you can still add your own modules. And the only reason you should install m2 via github is to play around with it and/or contribute to it. So this technically still makes `app/code` your playground.

Comment: @Sukeshini. Not sure about it, but I think you should.

Comment: @Marius agreed w/ everything you said I would have just said `app/code/Vendor` is your playground so no risk to break core stuff

Answer (score 2):

`app/code` is definitely the right place for the modules of your projet.

You must never write code inside `vendor`(this directory is not ignored into your source control), since it is managed by composer only and is dedicated to third party module or module you want to reuse (and you have published on packagist or your own satis repository).